# Is it valid to build a SEM with binary data and Likert data?

Tags: r, binary-data, structural-equation-modeling, likert, latent-variable

I have a survey with 129 respondents, no missing data and I have 3 independent variables (Communication, legitimacy and rewards system) and 1 dependent variable (Organization breakdown)

Communication and legitimacy were measured in a **5 point-Likert scale**. Reward system was measured with **binary data** and Organization breakdown composed of **binary data**.

I'm doing a PCA for the binary data and likert.

**Questions:
Is it valid to build latent variables like this?
Could I do a SEM with that information?**

This is the model I'm doing:

[image: Latent variables for SEM]

I'm using R, any help welcome.

Comment: Gaussian networks built with data that are binary still estimate regression effects that are proportion differences. Undirected effects are difficult to interpret (covariances are scaled differently). Use the robust covariance option to obtain correct SEs and p-values.

Comment: In R, how can I do what you are saying?

Comment: @AdamO you are saying that covariances for binary and Likert are scaled differently, right?

Comment: SEM and path models still use the empirical covariance, but whereas the regression coefficient is a mean difference, the covariance of binary RVs has no interpretation I'm aware of.

Comment: This was marked as off topic - but it seems to be exactly on topic, to me. Why is it thought to be off topic?

Comment: Can you do a path diagram that actually represents the model you plan to run?

Comment: what is the problem you see with the path diagram I posted? @JeremyMiles

Comment: It doesn't follow the usual rules of path diagrams, where each variable is a box or ellipse and each parameter is an arrow. Search for path diagrams for examples (if you want to).

Comment: (I think the model is valid, but I'm not sure 'cos I don't fully understand the model, so I don't want to commit to saying that it's valid without more information.)